# How can I calculate the number of cases in SPSS?

Tags: spss

[image: Each column shows the types of tools used. The last column shows how many tools are used.]

I would like to calculate the last column with SPSS without turning the columns into 1.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `COUNT` command to do this, small example below.

```
DATA LIST FREE / Tool1 Tool2 Tool3.
BEGIN DATA
1 3 8
1 5 1
1 . .
2 3 .
3 . .
END DATA.

COUNT Tool# = Tool1 TO Tool3 (LOWEST THRU HIGHEST).
EXECUTE.
```

Comment: Or use `compute Tool# = nvalid(Tool1 TO Tool3)`.